# Visualforce Render as PDF - Full width footer

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I'm working with renderasPDF to create a PDF-document of a Visualforce page. I know how to use repeating footers and stuff, so that is all working. But the problem I'm facing now is how to have a full width footer with only one div. Because you have bottom-left/center/right. I only want to use the center to have a full width footer. Something like in the image below. Does anyone have the solution for this?

PS: Don't mind the border of the footer, that one was the bad version in Word which I'm 'translating' into SF ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a complete solution, but I gave the bottom-left/center/right all the same mark-up. Except for center, I gave it the extra attribute 'white-space: nowrap;'. This allows the text to flow out of the bottom-center footer. You do have to fill the other 2 bottoms(left & right) with 
 to get the correct effect.